# Entity Framework timeout not triggered

Tags: entity-framework

Recently we ran into an issue where a process that normally took seconds to execute one day took an hour and then the next day took almost 9 hours.   That is a separate issue which I am also investigating, but issue I want to talk about here is the fact that the query in question was called through Entity Framework with a 600 second timeout and when the process started running long, there was no timeout exception triggered.

In each instance of the process running long, it eventually completed successfully with no errors generated. We do not override anything related to DbContext so the default timeout of 30 seconds should still apply.

We validated that the query was still running by evaluating current executions on the SQL Server instance. My first thought was that the query finished but goofiness with Entity Key columns in the entity class for this view caused it to take forever to validate.  There is only 1 Entity Key column on that object and it is the PK of the main table of the view.  We also confirmed that the dataset was not returning duplicate records. So everything points to the fact that the query is executing for the duration of the process and no timeout exceptions are being generated.

Has anyone ever experienced such a thing with EF in their own environment?

We are on EntityFramework 6.1.3 and SQL Server Standard 2016 SP2 CU4.

**CODE SAMPLE:**

EntitiesCommandTimeout=600

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains("EntitiesCommandTimeout"))
{
    _entitiesCommandTimeout = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EntitiesCommandTimeout"].ToString());
}

...

using (var db = new myContext())
{
    db.Database.CommandTimeout = _entitiesCommandTimeout;
    List<vwMyView> myViewItems = db.myView.Where(v => v.myColumn == myVariable).ToList();                
}
```

**UPDATE  2019-03-19:**
I forgot to mention that when one of my developers ran this process locally through Visual Studio and the config file set to match what we have setup in Prod, the timeout exception was properly triggered.

Comment: Are you sure the query doesn't trigger a massive amount of subsequent queries triggered by lazy loading?

Comment: I am sure.  The object has no related entities.  It is just a representation of a view.

Comment: Weird. It's unlikely that an ADO.Net command (which it is in the end) will ignore a command timeout. How does the SQL query itself behave when executed in SSMS?

Comment: Well, that is tricky.   When we just take q.ToString(), create a variable for the parameter, and then run it the query came back in 3 seconds.   What we didn't do is to run it exactly like EF does using sp_executesql().   Also, a restore of Production to a test environment from right before the process initially executed saw that process finish in 12 seconds which is the expected amount of time.   That leads me to believe that the query plan got regenerated for some reason and messed up the row estimates.   That is a whole other investigation that we have going on.

Comment: A minimum verifiable example is needed. Normally EF does adhere to timeout settings, such as due to transaction locking. Common culprits for unexpected delays are locks/deadlocks but creating a view and simulating an open lock by creating a Tx and inserting a record in the DB without a commit or rollback and EF trips the timeout as expected. Are there any default timeouts set on your command line? What is the isolation level on your production database? ("DBCC useroptions")

Comment: Isolation Level = Read Committed Snapshot
lock_timeout = -1

Not sure what you mean by "default timeouts set on your command line".  Can you clarify?